# Changing lock screen image in Windows 8.1 via background task

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, lockscreen

In main(foreground) app i can use LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync method to set the lockscreen image.
I couldn't able to figure out how to set the lockscreen images regular basis (every x hours) from the code. In WP8, we can use background task to update the lockscreen.

And changing lockscreen image doesn't qualify as lockscreen apps (badge/badge+text). Is it even possible with current 8.1 lockscreen API's?

Comment: Did you found an answer for this question?

Comment: yes, i created a timer background task for my win8 app and used SetImageFileAsync method to update the lockscreen image in the background.

Comment: can you please upload your solution here.? Thanks

Comment: can you please provide me the exact solution.? I need to change the background image in wp8.1?